# Sequel gem identity / natural element

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am trying to use a reduce function to &-connect multiple sequel expressions. However in the beginning I'd have the need for a natural element / identity element Sequel-expression. i.e. an expression that can be &-connected without changing the meaning of the query. I tried just using nil, but that does not seem to work. Is there such a thing?^^

Imagine the following

```
def reduce(buffer, array, &func)
  return buffer if array.empty?

  if buffer.nil? # I basically want to get rid of this
    reduce(array[0], array[1..-1], &func)
  else
    reduce(func.call(buffer, array[0]), array[1..-1], &func)
  end
end

# to be able to call:
reduce(NATURAL_ELEMENT, array_of_expressions) { |first, second| first & second }
```

When calling `Sequel.expr(nil)` I get a `#<Sequel::SQL::Wrapper @value=>nil>` but I don't know exactly what effect that has. Is this what I am looking for?

Comment: Do you have an example for  NATURAL_ELEMENT and  array_of_expressions?

Comment: ok, let's have a look at how reduce would work for summing up numbers:
`reduce(0, [1, 2, 3, 4]) { |first, second| first + second }`.

0 is the natural / identity element of addition and then you have an array of the elements you want to call the given function on.

Comment: How about `[1,2,3,4].reduce(0){|a,b| a+b}` or just `[1,2,3,4].reduce(&:+)` ?

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, I am actually looking for the natural element for Sequel expressions, an array of sequel expressions might look like this:
`[Sequel.expr(field: 1), Sequel.expr(field2: 2)]`

Comment: I know. That's why I asked for concrete examples for your array_of_expressions.

Comment: So I need something where
`something & Sequel.expr(field: 1) == Sequel.expr(field: 1)`

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a *universal set*, i.e. a set containing all possible elements. This is the identity for set intersections. If you use `Sequel.expr(nil)`, you'll have the equivalent of an empty set.

I'm not aware of any universal set (or other identity object) in Sequel, but you could try to implement one. Here's an example (using the `Singleton` module for good measure):

```
require "singleton"

class UniversalSet
  include Singleton

  def &(other)
    other
  end
end

UNIVERSAL_SET = UniversalSet.instance
```

Now you can use this in set intersection operations. The type of the elements is irrelevant, so it works fine for `SQL` objects, as well.

```
UNIVERSAL_SET & [1, 2, 3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want to, you can also implement the other set operations for the universal set.

This, however, has the downside that it is not commutative. If you try the inverse:

```
[1, 2, 3] & UNIVERSAL_SET
```

it will throw an error. This is a limitation in the available coercion constructs in Ruby. (Currently you can only overload operators commutatively for numbers.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's your `something` for which `something & Sequel.expr(field: 1) == Sequel.expr(field: 1)`:

```
class IdentityFunction
   def self.&(b)
    b
  end
end

IdentityFunction & "test" #=> "test"
IdentityFunction & 3 #=> 3
```

You can write :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]].reduce(IdentityFunction){|a,b| a & b} #=> [3, 4]
```

Please note that [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) takes the first element as start value by default, so `IdentityFunction` isn't even needed :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]].reduce{|a,b| a & b} #=> [3, 4]
```

Which means what you want to achieve could probably be written as :

```
array_of_expressions.reduce{ |first, second| first & second }
```

or just

```
array_of_expressions.reduce(&:&)
```